# Reduce number of frames per second fps in Opnecv 3.2.0

Tags: opencv, opencv3.2

I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 and I want to limit the fps. I am reading video from a saved file. I am using the below code, but fps remains same even after setting the property to limit fps. Even setting width and height of the video also unchanged.

Is there any way to do this.

```
import cv2

# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('aa.mp4')

setfps = cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) #Default is 25.
setwidth = cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640) #default 1920
setheight = cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480) #default 1080
```

Comment: You must surely have a loop that is displaying your frames on the screen? If so, put a 30ms delay on the `waitKey()` if you want 30fps, or 25ms if you want 40 fps.

Comment: These settings are meaningful when you're reading from a camera. You're reading from a file. Setting FPS has absolutely no effect in that case. Nor will setting a different size -- you get what's in the file, as fast as the decoder can decode it. If you want different size, resize the frame yourself after you read it. If you want it slower, then wast some time between iterations (e.g. sleep).